# EXCEL application updating event

Tags: excel, vba, rtd

Most of the cells in my worksheet receives RTD data once per second and a lot of calculations are done when the data is refreshed. It's becoming really slow. If I set Application.ScreenUpdating to false, does it mean even if the most recent data is not refreshed on the screen, but the functions will still be calculated using the latest values?

For example, I have cell C1:C300, which is updated once per second. Another column D1:D300 uses the values from C1:C300 to compute some formula. Now if I set the Application.ScreenUpdating to false but Calculation Mode to automatic, will I speed things up without causing any problems? I mean, I can't tell from the screen whether calculations in D1:D300 are calculated using the new data in C or not?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Application.ScreenUpdating=false does not affect Automatic calculation so thats OK. But Application.screenUpdating automagically gets switched back on when your VBA exits back to Excel. 
 So it might be better to control both Calculation and Screenupdating from VBA